# Multiple "multiple definition of ..." while compiling simple Hello World

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I was compiling the simple Hello World in Eclipse C/C++ Mars Edition using MinGW.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

Compiler flags:

```
-I"H:\Eclipse\Workspace\Project" -O0 -Wall -static -static-libgcc
```

Errors:

```
multiple definitions of '__gcc_deregister_frame'
multiple definitions of '__gcc_register_frame'
multiple definitions of '_argc'
multiple definitions of '_argv'
multiple definitions of '_mingw32_init_mainargs'
multiple definitions of '_onexit'
multiple definitions of 'atexit'
multiple definitions of 'mainCRTStartup'
multiple definitions of 'WinMainCRTStartup;
```

Comment: Get rid of the `-static-libgcc` it's added by the linker automatically. Also for c++ it should be `-static-libstdc++`

Comment: FWIW, I am unable to reproduce this, using the (cross-compiling) command `mingw32-g++ -O0 -Wall -static -static-libgcc foo.cpp`; (notwithstanding that some flags may be redundant, it both compiles and links successfully). You need to a) learn to test compiling commands from the command line, (without relying on any IDE as a crutch), and b) show the __full__ text of the command which your IDE has invoked on your behalf. This does not appear to be a MinGW issue; more likely a problem with your IDE/project configuration.

Answer (score 2):

**MinGW** links the standard libraries by default, **libstdc++** as static, **libgcc** as shared (because of his roots from Unix GCC). `-static` usually is a shortcut for `-static-libgcc`, the opposite would be `-shared-libgcc` (useful if the compiler links statically by default, like **TDM GCC**).

Your combination of both static links is redundant (see [GCC links options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)), just use `static`. You get only these few symbols, because the optimizer throws away what don't get used.

The main problem may be, that you don't compile multiple object files and link once, instead you link all of them with the standard libraries and finally them together.

Comment: "Didn't work" is the least useful answer someone can give! What happened? Did the error message change and how she looks completely? What's your current command line (completely)? Which MinGW project did you use? Be more specific, i don't like to guess.

Comment: I used the same project as before. The error message didn't change at all. Compiler flags are as follows `-I"H:\Eclipse\Workspace\Project" -O0 -Wall` now.

Comment: Specification of the same __library__ multiple times __doesn't__ cause multiple definition errors; those multiple definitions must originate in free-standing __object files__, (either as repeat definitions in one or more source translation units, or as repeated specification of the same object file to the linker).

Comment: @KeithMarshall In far past, i really had this problem that the GCC compiler doesn't recognize multiple same links, but you're right, shouldn't be these days. That's why i asked the questioner to show his whole command and error message. At the end i guess he just misses compile option `-c` and links, links, links (answer updated).